# Need to check whether a credit card expiry date is valid in java

Tags: java, eclipse

I am creating a system using java in eclipse where the user is going to enter their expiry date (month and year only) when prompted. I will then need to perform a check to check whether this is valid: i.e the month and year entered is not before the current month and year.

I have tried searching on here and elsewhere but could only find solutions which would compare the day and/or time. Is there any way that I could compare only the month and year to the current date?

I'm relatively new to coding so apologies if this is actually quite simple.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO! What have you tried so far?

Comment: I would try searching stackoverflow, because you are probably not the first person to try and do this in Java

Comment: I personally would not provide any information which is on my card to a site/snippet which has had to resort to Stack overflow for a solution. I would not recommend expanding into asking for the full 16 digit code

Comment: This is not going to be a live system, nobody is actually going to be entering their card information...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code seems to have worked for me:

```
     String input = keyboard.next();
    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/yy");
    simpleDateFormat.setLenient(false);
    Date expiry = simpleDateFormat.parse(input);
    boolean expired = expiry.before(new Date());
    if (expired == true)
    {
        System.out.println("This card has already expired");
    }
```

Comment: This will show as expired if the current month is the card expiry month...